# Pass parameter to function with addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I have an anonymous function

```
function getStocks(item){
   alert(item);
}
```

Below is my click event listener.

```
document.getElementById("passBtn").addEventListener("click", getStocks, false);
```

I need to pass a parameter to `getStocks()`. I tried the below but does not work. What's wrong?

```
document.getElementById("passBtn").addEventListener('click', function(){
  getStocks(item);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the javascript `bind` function:

```
var item = "item";
document.getElementById("passBtn").addEventListener("click", 
    getStocks.bind(null, item), false);
```

See the above code in action, here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4m7L8u6/)

See more information, here: [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: thanks. Instead of `.bind`, why doesn't `.on` work ?

Comment: What you're doing in the `bind` function is binding parameters to the function for when the event handler invokes it. `on` is syntactic sugar for adding event listeners in jQuery, which is something entirely different.

Comment: @Bekki If the answer is correct, remember to mark the question as completed :)